# Bootstrap 4 Navigation Doesn't Hide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 in a Ruby on Rails 5 project, and my navigation doesn't hide after showing. At the appropriate breakpoint, a click event will drop the nav menu down, but clicking again does nothing. The menu stays dropped. I've inspected in Chrome, and while there are no errors being thrown, the navigation (div.collapse.navbar-collapse#navigation) is not removing the "show" class after applying it. `aria-expanded="true"` also sticks around on the button.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light">
    <%= link_to(root_path, class: "navbar-brand") do %>
      <% if current_page?(root_path) %>
        <%= inline_svg "caples_logo_cir.svg", size: "60", id: "welcome-logo", class: "d-inline-block align-middle", nocomment: true, preserve_aspect_ratio: 'xMaxYMax meet', data: {alt: "Caples Web Design logo"} %>
      <% else %>
        <%= inline_svg "caples_logo_cir.svg", size: "60", id: "logo", class: "d-inline-block align-middle", nocomment: true, preserve_aspect_ratio: 'xMaxYMax meet', data: {alt: "Caples Web Design logo"} %>
      <% end %>
      <span class="brand-title align-middle">Caples Web Design</span>
    <% end %>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" aria-controls="navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <%= link_to "About", about_path, class: "nav-item nav-link" %>
        <%= link_to "Contact", contact_path, class: "nav-item nav-link" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Can anyone help me identify this problem?

Comment: Can you see if something else is being changed in the dom when you click the button? Both classes (button and div) should change. Which version of jquery are you using? is there another element in the dom with the same id (navigation)? Try changing that id as well to see what happens.

Comment: The `button`'s class and `aria-expanded` both attempt to change, but they don't. The `div` briefly adds the "collapsing" class like it should, but the "show" class doesn't get replaced by the "hide" class. I'm using the `jquery-rails` gem, version 4.3.1.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap-rubygem? please publish part of your gem file where the dependencies for bootstrap are shown, with their versions: bootstrap, jquery, popper, etc so we can have a closer look. Also, is this the only component that is not behaving as it should?

Comment: Here's part of my Gemfile:
```
ruby '2.4.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sassc'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
```

Comment: Well this is a tough one... Can you create just a mock app with only a very simple view with just html components and static values to see if it works in a very simple scenario? A different solution would be to add the libraries using CDN and not the gem file, just to see if there is something not working properly with the libraries.